# $\text{Int}\ B^n - 0$ is contractible where $n \gt 2$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have seen that $\text{Int}\  B^n - 0$ is contractible, where $B^n$ is the unit closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $n \gt 2$. How can I show that this space is contractible? I couldn't think of any homotopy between the identity map and the constant map. Moreover, is $B^n - 0$ also contractible? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid 0 < \|x\| < 1\}$ is not contractible. It is homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write that $n \gt 2$.

Comment: Don't you mean "simply connected"?

Comment: @PeterFranek I know it's simply connected since it deformation retracts to $S^{n-1}$, but I saw from a source, Problem 5 in, https://www.math.psu.edu/ballif/assignments/Math%20527%20Topology-Geometry/MATH527_HW7.pdf, that it is contractible, so I was wondering why.

Comment: As others pointed out, the sphere is not contractible. It is in some sense topologically very complicated and for example higher homotopy groups of spheres are far from understood.

Comment: Nowhere in Problem 5 of the link you provided does it say that $\text{Int} B^n - 0$ is contractible.

Comment: @LeeMosher It says "The space U ∩ V has trivial fundamental group since it is homeomorphic to Bn − x0 (also a contractible space)."

Comment: You are right, it does say that. And that is an error committed by the person who wrote the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The space is not contractible. The space retracts to $S^{n-1}$ by radial projection $x\mapsto \frac{x}{||x||}$. The sphere is not contractible by algebraic topology, for the homology group $H^{n-1}(S^{n-1};\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}\not=0$.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write that $n \gt 2$

Comment: Still it is not contractible.